# How to mock Session.request without losing auth?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests

When testing Python software that uses the requests library, it is advised to mock `requests.sessions.Session.request`.

Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work very well when having to deal with HTTP Authentication, I feel like I am mocking a too high abstraction layer in requests. How can I intercept/mock requests such that I don't have to deal with authentication myself (and just get the appropriate headers)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mock the `Session`, use a `Transport Adapter`. =)

The `Session` object does substantial processing on the request, and patching it at that level won't get you the request.

Instead, write a `Transport Adapter` whose `send()` method stores off the `PreparedRequest` object.

For examples, see [the official docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#transport-adapters) and [an article I wrote](https://lukasa.co.uk/2012/12/Writing_A_Transport_Adapter/). However, you'll want something like this:

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter


class TestAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    """
    A Transport Adapter that stores all requests sent, and provides pre-canned responses.
    """
    def __init__(self, responses):
        self.responses = responses
        self.requests = requests

    def send(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.requests.append(request)
        return self.responses.pop(0)
```

To get this to work `responses` will need to be a list of `urllib3.Response` objects or something similar that Requests can work with. `TestAdapter.requests` will be a list of `requests.PreparedRequest` objects.

If you don't want to do all this work, you can try something like [betamax](http://betamax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Excellent thanks! Since i wanted this to work for all sessions, i ended up mocking `HTTPAdapter.send`.